# Practicing with Spark's join and scala on Array[String]

Tags: arrays, scala, apache-spark

I am new to both Spark and Scala, and I'm trying to practice the [join](https://spark.apache.org/docs/0.6.2/api/core/spark/PairRDDFunctions.html) command in Spark.

I have two csv files:

Ads.csv is

```
5de3ae82-d56a-4f70-8738-7e787172c018,AdProvider1
f1b6c6f4-8221-443d-812e-de857b77b2f4,AdProvider2
aca88cd0-fe50-40eb-8bda-81965b377827,AdProvider1
940c138a-88d3-4248-911a-7dbe6a074d9f,AdProvider3
983bb5e5-6d5b-4489-85b3-00e1d62f6a3a,AdProvider3
00832901-21a6-4888-b06b-1f43b9d1acac,AdProvider1
9a1786e1-ab21-43e3-b4b2-4193f572acbc,AdProvider1
50a78218-d65a-4574-90de-0c46affbe7f3,AdProvider5
d9bb837f-c85d-45d4-95f2-97164c62aa42,AdProvider4
611cf585-a8cf-43e9-9914-c9d1dc30dab5,AdProvider1
```

Impression.csv is:

```
5de3ae82-d56a-4f70-8738-7e787172c018,Publisher1
f1b6c6f4-8221-443d-812e-de857b77b2f4,Publisher2
aca88cd0-fe50-40eb-8bda-81965b377827,Publisher1
940c138a-88d3-4248-911a-7dbe6a074d9f,Publisher3
983bb5e5-6d5b-4489-85b3-00e1d62f6a3a,Publisher3
00832901-21a6-4888-b06b-1f43b9d1acac,Publisher1
9a1786e1-ab21-43e3-b4b2-4193f572acbc,Publisher1
611cf585-a8cf-43e9-9914-c9d1dc30dab5,Publisher1
```

I want to join them with the first ID as the key and two values.

So I read them in like this:

```
val ads = sc.textFile("ads.csv")
ads: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[String] = MapPartitionsRDD[1] at textFile  at <console>:21
val impressions = sc.textFile("impressions.csv")
impressions: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[String] = MapPartitionsRDD[3] at textFile at <console>:21
```

Ok, so I have to make key,value pairs:
    val adPairs = ads.map(line => line.split(","))
    val impressionPairs = impressions.map(line => line.split(","))

```
res11: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[Array[String]] = MapPartitionsRDD[6] at map at <console>:23
res13: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[Array[String]] = MapPartitionsRDD[7] at map at <console>:23
```

But I can't join them:

```
val result = impressionPairs.join(adPairs)
<console>:29: error: value join is not a member of       org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[Array[String]]
val result = impressionPairs.join(adPairs)
```

Do I need to convert the pairs into another format?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are almost there, but what you need is to transform the Array[String] into key-value pairs, like this:

```
val adPairs = ads.map(line => {
  val substrings = line.split(",")
  (substrings(0), substrings(1))
})
```

(and the same for `impressionPairs`)

That will give you rdds of type `RDD[(String, String)]` which can then be joined :)

Comment: I get the error `<console>:45: error: value split is not a member of (org.apache.spark.graphx.VertexId, String)
         val substrings = line.split(",")`

Comment: My two arrays are in the form `mVP: Array[(org.apache.spark.graphx.VertexId, Int)]`, `cPV: Array[(org.apache.spark.graphx.VertexId, String)]` and I wan't to join `mVP` and `cPV` by `VertexId`

Comment: The `split` operator works on type `String` - not on type `(org.apache.spark.graphx.VertexId, String)`. But if you want to play with Spark, you should probably start by converting your arrays into RDDs with `sc.parallelize`